# QRCode decode error: fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, winforms

I used a program to encode a text into QR image. 
I set the size QRCodeScale from 8 to 24 with combo box.
I used MessagingToolkit.QRCode package.
I got one error from decode when I put a large text into 24 scale and error point to txtQR.Text row code:

```
    MessagingToolkit.QRCode.ExceptionHandler.InvalidVersionException: 
'Value does not fall within the expected range.'
```

About decode :

```
    private void btn_Decode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog()
        { Filter = "PNG Files (*.png)|*.png", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false })
        {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                pictureBoxQR.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
                pictureBoxQR.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;                 
                MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeDecoder decoder = new MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeDecoder();
                txtQR.Text = decoder.Decode(new QRCodeBitmapImage(pictureBoxQR.Image as Bitmap));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like this API cannot decode images exceeding a certain size. I fail to find any documentation clearly state this limitation, though. You can raise a question in the support site. By the way, the `QRCodeScale` of 24 means 24 pixels for a dot, so the outcome image is very large, it is not necessary to use a scale so large. In my test, set it as 1 is good enough to decode for the barcode scanner on my phone.

Comment: the size can be the problem into sized definition area. Anyway, this websites can be a source but I don't find anything http://platform.twit88.com/projects/mt-qrcode / http://twit88.com/home/opensource/qrcode - no changes from 5 years. Another way can be a debuging issue.

Comment: That is true, but still some admins are maintaining that site. I can get their source from GitHub or directly decompile from the DLL, but I cannot understand why it throws the "InvalidVersion"  (the version is expected to be within the range of from 1 to 40, but it is -14) and what this exception means.